# Catching mouse move

Tags: c#, .net, design-surface

### Situation :

I'm currently working a project where the aim is to develop a VS-like IDE, where users can drap/drop new controls to a design surface, and modify properties of these controls.

So i implemented `IDesignerHost, IServiceContainer, IContainer, IComponentChangeService,` and some others useful interface, made to design that.

Everything works fine, i've my toolbox, my design surface, and my `propertyGrid` working just fine.

### Problem is :

Attached to the drag'n'droped controls is a label, which **has to follow the control while the user move it with his mouse**.

I tried to use the `LocationChanged event` of the controls, to move the label when the control move. But this event occurs only one time, **after** the control has moved so the label doesn't move *while the control move*.

I'm not able to find a way for make this work. Does anyone have any good ideas please ?

Thank you

**Edit :**
I use a custom class, implementing IDesignerHost. Controls on this design surface doesn't fire events Mouse----- (e.g. : MouseDown, MouseMove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to do it :

I implemented `ISelectionService` and in the `SetSelectedComponents` function, I managed to select the label control associated with any selected control.

I overrided the designer of the label, so that no border/resize-rectangle would show when the label is selected.

This is a not very elegant solution, but it works well =).

Answer (score 1):

Every Control has a [ControlDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx), provides additional methods to support extending and altering the behavior of an associated Control at design time.

In the ControlDesigner, you have a [BehaviorService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.behavior.behaviorservice.aspx), which is responsible to control on DesignSurface behavior of the control.

BehaviorService has multiple [Glyph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.behavior.glyph.aspx)s and [Adorner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.behavior.adorner.aspx)s which are like UI decorators for the control. The control re-size rubber-band like rectangle is a Glyph, called System.Windows.Forms.Design.Behavior.SelectionBorderGlyph a private class to .Net 2.0.

This links might be of help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171820.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514670%28VS.90%29.aspx

You should be able to add your custom Glyph which has a Label attached with the Control.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, even though I'm not working on this project anymore. I'll take a look at it =)

Answer (score 0):

Form2 contains a `panel1, label1`

```
panel1.MouseMove += panel1_MouseMove
panel1.MouseDown += panel1_MouseDown
```

when `MouseDown+Left Button` clicked -> save initial mouse position
when `MouseMove+Left Button` clicked -> move (panel1+label1) by the difference between current mouse position and the saved initial position.

it's done.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private int _x, _y;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            panel1.Location = new Point(panel1.Location.X + (e.X - _x), panel1.Location.Y + (e.Y - _y));
            label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + (e.X - _x), label1.Location.Y + (e.Y - _y));
        }
    }

    private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            _x = e.X;
            _y = e.Y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but doesn't work on my project. I use a custom class, implementing IDesignerHost. Controls on this design surface doesn't fire events Mouse----- (e.g. : MouseDown, MouseMove).